# Displaying errors from different pages

Tags: php, redirect, header, gallery

Can anyone help me achieve this:

So basically, I have a gallery system, let's assume that I created a gallery on e.g gallery.php but then I realized that I don't like it - so I want to delete it. I have a link under the gallery that says delete e.g. `<a href="delete_gallery.php?id=1">Delete</a>`, whenever I click on the delete link and then when it successfully deletes it redirects me to `gallery.php` (and here's what I need), I want to display a message on `gallery.php` that a gallery has been deleted. This message should only be displayed when a user gets redirected from `delete_gallery.php?id=1` to `gallery.php` after a successfull removal of the gallery.

I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
if (empty($errors)) {
   delete_gallery($gallery_id);
   header('Location: gallery.php?delete_success');
   exit();
}
```

And now, I need a code that will display a message on gallery.php when a user got redirected to gallery.php?delete_success.

I tried my best explaining it but even I don't know what I am saying:D LOL!

@edit

Or maybe this might work:

```
if ($_GET == gallery.php?delete_success) {
   echo "Gallery successfully deleted.";
}
```

Do you think that this might work? (Haven't tried it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] == 'delete_success'){
 print 'Gallery deleted !';
}
```